# Stack Overflow images are broken

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Over the past couple of days I've noticed that images on the stack overflow site have broken links.  This error seems to be in both question and answer bodies, and sometimes author avatars.

Here's a clip of one such issue:

[image]

In fact, the preview of this post as I write this also has the error.  Talk about meta!

[image: meta image]

I've tried different browsers, even on my phone.  Is there an issue with Stack Overflow?

## Update

Because images are working for others, here's a dump of the Network loading of this page:

[image: Chrome network tab]

This looks like the [same DNS issues I had with Notion a week ago](https://www.notion.so/Focus-on-performance-reliability-89f937a6ccc04905b1dcfa878537e08d#93ccfad9658b421c9b862da917ab0343).  I suspect there's more problems with DNS entries in my local neighbourhood.

If this is the case I'm screwed; my provider (Telstra Australia) doesn't listen to their individual customers, only companies being affected by their service.  It will take StackOverflow contacting them to sort this issue out.

## Update 2

I found another computer in my house couldn't replicate the issues so I tried resetting my (Windows 10) network stack using [these instructions](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058982/ethernet-products.html) and it resolved the problem.

Strangely my mobile (which I initially used to verify the problem) now also works correctly as well.

While I'm still not sure what the cause was, it probably wasn't an issue with Stack Overflow so I'm closing this question.

Comment: Both images here work for me. You can check the dev tools in your browser and see what the "network" tells you. There you can see if you get a 404 or any other response for those images.

Comment: I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to retrieve from `https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca7BH.png`. This issue seems to have similar symptoms to the DNS issue I had with Notion earlier this week: `https://www.notion.so/Focus-on-performance-reliability-89f937a6ccc04905b1dcfa878537e08d#93ccfad9658b421c9b862da917ab0343`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I created the question and it doesn't appear to be an issue with Stack Overflow.

Comment: use a vpn or a private socks5/ssh tunnel proxy if you have a dodgy isp

Comment: Just use google dns servers...

Comment: Changing my DNS server didn't help.